# Dockerfile build successful with docker but fails with kaniko

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, cicd, kaniko

I have a java dockerfile and i can build it successfully with

`docker build .`

command.

But the problem is when i want to build it with kaniko in my gitlab ci pipeline, i got the following error :

```
INFO[0172] Taking snapshot of full filesystem... 

153error building image: error building stage: failed to take snapshot: Failed to get file info for /root/.kotlin/daemon/kotlin-daemon.17994.run: lstat /root/.kotlin/daemon/kotlin-daemon.17994.run: no such file or directory
```

It worth noting that sometimes kaniko build is successful and sometimes it fail
s.

Comment: seems the thing failing is the snapshot, I assume that has nothing to do with docker

Comment: @Matthias so how can i fix that in your opinion ?

Comment: absolutely no idea, you have to look that up online, that is not related to docker at all I think and depends completely on what's going on on your machine

Comment: would also need to see the Dockerfile

Comment: @amir did you ever fix this problem? I just got the same error.

Comment: Got the same issue on my end, seems intermittent because after several retries it finally passed successfully. This is definitely something going wrong with kaniko.